# Android : ListView Not Using OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I am using Fragment type of Class but my ListView not using onItemclickListner, how can I use onclick event on listview. i already tried focusable = false, that's not working.please Suggest me some solution.

```
public class HomePage extends SherlockListFragment {
    String postid, date, title, content, image;
    String PostID,Date,Title,Image, Content; 
    TextView detail;
    ListView lv;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> listtitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> listDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Drawable> cIcons = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);;
    ActionBar ab = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
    ab.getDisplayOptions();
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    ab.setTitle("मुख्य पृष्ठ");
    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.duk);
    ProcessIt p = new ProcessIt();
    p.execute();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage, container, false);      
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                list.add(title+image+date+postid);  
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NewPage.class);                    
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

private class ProcessIt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        try {               
            String response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet
                    ("http://*********api.aspx?function=GetPost");              
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(response));
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("postid")) {
                        postid = xpp.nextText();
                        PostID = postid.trim();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("date")) {
                        date = xpp.nextText();
                        Date = date.trim();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        title = xpp.nextText();
                        Title = title.trim();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("content")) {
                        content = xpp.nextText();
                        Content = content.trim();
                        list.add(Title+Image+Date+PostID);                              
                        listtitle.add(Title);
                        cIcons.add(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon));
                        listDetails.add(Content+"\n"+Date + "  << detail"); 
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
                        image = xpp.nextText();
                        Image = image.trim();
                        }
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        try {
            if (prog.isShowing()) {
                prog.dismiss();
            }       
            if(list.size()<=0){              
                list.add(Title+Image+Date+PostID);                              
                listtitle.add(Title);            
                cIcons.add(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star));
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        prog.setMessage("Loading...Please Wait");
        prog.show();
        prog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
}

public Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {            
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                CustomListAdaptor adaptor = createAdapter();
                if (adaptor != null) {
                    lv.setAdapter(adaptor);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

public CustomListAdaptor createAdapter() {
    CustomListAdaptor adapter = null;       
    if (list != null) { 
        adapter = new CustomListAdaptor(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, list, listtitle, listDetails,cIcons);
    }
    return adapter;
}
}
```

Layout of class file is here..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/firstheading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txt1"
    android:textColor="#D12F2F"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/firstheading"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#666666"
    android:dividerHeight="2.0sp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Comment: first of all tell me you display your ListView properly?

Comment: Post your **homepage** layout xml file.

Comment: Have you set **focusable = false** for ListView??

Comment: yes i tried focusable = false

Comment: finally OnItemClickListener worked by using it inside the OnActivitycreated Method... :)